# MySQL: could not select data with time range

Tags: mysql

I wanted to select data, if date is matched and time is in between start time and end time. I have tried in many ways, but i am not succeed.

**check 3rd row in data table in below, start time 08:00:00 and end time is 11:00:00. it means 09:00:00 is between 08:00:00 and 11:00:00**

**Here is my Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM (`rides`) WHERE `date` = '2013/04/30' AND `start_time` >= '9:00:00' AND `end_time` <= '9:00:00'
```

**Table structure** if you need to know the datatype of field:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rides` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...,
  ...,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `start_time` time NOT NULL,
  `end_time` time NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=19 ;
```

**Data in table:**

[image: Data in table]

Comment: **dashes** but **slashes**. Too localized

Comment: From looking at your data, the query should execute correctly, but return no data because none of the rows in the data set have that right date and time combinations.  Are you getting an error?

Comment: can you select and copy paste data here instead of the picture ?

Comment: sorry, i dont know much about dashes and slashes in date. but it is working for me. @YourCommonSense

Comment: sorry, i am not getting any error. @jeffery_the_wind

Comment: what you need? all data in sql format or text format? @echo_me

Comment: If you're not getting an error, then there is nothing wrong with your query.  You are just not getting any data because none of your data fits the criteria that you have specified.

Comment: check 3rd row, start time 08:00:00 and end time is 11:00:00. it means 09:00:00 is between 08:00:00 and 11:00:00

Comment: @itskawsar text format, like in this picture but writen not as picture , i cant select the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote :

> check 3rd row (...) it means 09:00:00 is between 08:00:00 and 11:00:00

I am assuming you expect this row in your result set. Obviously, your `WHERE` condition is wrong. What you want is:

```
WHERE ... start_time <= '9:00:00' AND '9:00:00' <= end_time
```

or alternatively

```
WHERE ... '09:00:00' BETWEEN start_time AND end_time
```

Notice the leading `0` is required in the above example. A more canonical form would be:

```
WHERE ... CAST('9:00:00' AS TIME) BETWEEN start_time AND end_time
```

Comment: Great answer. As followed your answer, finally i solved. Here is my final query: `SELECT * FROM (rides) WHERE date = '2013/04/30' AND CAST('8:00:00' AS TIME) BETWEEN start_time AND end_time` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use between clause of MySQL
Have a look here
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm

Comment: they are using between clause for one field. but i have two fields and one data :(

Comment: See if it works:
SELECT * FROM rides WHERE date = '2013/05/1' AND (start_time >= '8:00:00' AND end_time <= '11:00:00')

Answer (score -1):

From looking at your data, the query should not return any data because there are no suitable rows of data in your table.