# Searching time range not working in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime, time

I have this two queries. My first query is to check the materials availability, and this is also the main problem that i'm encountering right now. It will select all the materials that has been reserved at a time.
So I have this table date for  schedule_dummy table:
Note: I'm using codeigniter.

```
   CREATE TABLE schedule_dummy
   (
        `materialID` int,
        `date_reserve` date,
        `start_time` time,
        `end_time` time
   );

              ------DB Table schedule_dummy --------
   materialID  |  date_reserve  |   start_time   | end_time   
   ----------------------------------------------------------
       7       |    2013-08-31   |  13:00:00     | 13:30:00    
       8       |    2013-08-31   |  13:00:00     | 14:00:00   
   ----------------------------------------------------------
```

My second query is to retrieve the materials where_not_in the id that has been retrieve from the first query. And I have this table date for materials table:

```
                  ------DB Table materials--------
       id     |    cid      |     mname         |   mdesc    
   ----------------------------------------------------------
       7      |     1       |     accer         |  acer   
       10     |     1       |     scanner       |  scanner
       12     |     1       |     prjector      |  scanner
   ----------------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried [MySQL: could not select data with time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298319/mysql-could-not-select-data-with-time-range).
I've been through many research but still don't get what I needed.

So this is the my whole function look like:

```
   function check_materials(){
    //$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);

    $start =  date("H:i:s", strtotime($this->input->post('start')));
    $end =  date("H:i:s", strtotime($this->input->post('end')));
    $date_reserve =  $this->input->post('date_reserve');
    $id =  $this->input->post('id');

    $sql = "SELECT id, materialID FROM schedule_dummy WHERE date_reserve = ? AND time(?) BETWEEN start_time AND end_time AND time(?) BETWEEN start_time AND end_time";      
    $query = $this->db->query($sql,array($date_reserve,$start,$end));

    $ids = array();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0 ){
        foreach($query->result() as $rows){
            $ids[] = $rows->materialID;
        }
    }

    $data = array();
    $n = count($ids);

    $idz = array();
    if($n > 0){
        $q = $this->db->select('*')->where_not_in('id',$ids)->where('cid', $id)->get('materials');

        if($q->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach($q->result() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }else{
        $q = $this->db->select('*')->where('cid',$id)->get('materials');

        if($q->num_rows() > 0 ){
            foreach($q->result() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }

}
```

In this query the problem is when I select the `start_time = 13:30:00` to `end_time = 14:00:00` then the data from schedule_dummy with the `materialID` of `8` doesn't retrieve. Since the start_time and end_time is from `13:00:00` to `14:00:00`.

And also when I try this:

```
$sql = "
SELECT materialID 
FROM schedule_dummy 
WHERE 
  date_reserve = ? 
 AND start_time >= time(?) AND end_time <= time(?)";
```

When I select the same input it doesn't retrieve the data from schedule_dummy.
So what do you think where i'm having mistake in here? Does my logic is wrong? Or any of my queries? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the data using >= AND <= in a 12hr time format in php/mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531453/how-to-get-the-data-using-and-in-a-12hr-time-format-in-php-mysql)

Comment: @Venkat: Yah it's also my thread. But it's not the same case. And please kindly read my problem.

Comment: Please show the structure of your table: `describe schedule_dummy`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, I believe, that MySQL is doing string comparison between your stored dates and parameter dates. The automatic conversion of `DATETIME` and `TIME` columns to strings yields stuff you don't expect. MySQL thinks a raw date (without a time) has a zero time.

Try this (see the `DATE(?)`?)  :

```
 SELECT materialID 
   FROM schedule_dummy 
  WHERE date_reserve = DATE(?) 
    AND start_time >= TIME(?) 
    AND end_time <= TIME(?)
```

Check this sqlfiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecc35/12/0

Note: some folks use `<` rather than `<=` for an ending time comparison, so contiguous time intervals don't logically overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Finally find the solution. I've `changed` the datatype of `start_time` and `end_time` to `DATETIME` and used this query.

```
   $sql = "SELECT materialID 
           FROM schedule_dummy
           WHERE  date_reserve = DATE(?)
           AND TIME(?) BETWEEN start_time AND end_time
           OR TIME(?) BETWEEN start_time AND end_time";
```